# How to test conditional rendering of components using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a conditional rendering block in my React component which is defined as:

```
 {(props.email.primary.isPending) ?
          <PendingComponent emailAddress={props.email.primary.pendingEmail} />
          :
          <SecondaryEmailContact
            state={props.email.secondary}
            retrieveInputData={props.retrieveInputData}
            handleSecondaryEmailToggle={props.handleSecondaryEmailToggle}
            handleDelete={props.handleDelete}
            handleSubmitContact={props.handleSubmitContact}
            refs={props.refs}
          />
        }
```

I have written a test case as below:

```
it('renders the EditEmailContact component', () => {
        wrapper=mount(<EditEmailContact 
          email={emailState}
          handleSecondaryEmailToggle={handleSecondaryEmailToggleFn}
          retrieveInputData={retrieveInputDataFn}
          handleDelete={handleDeleteFn}
          handleSubmitContact={handleSubmitContactFn} />);
    });
  });
```

So, in my test result it shows the line where the statement for conditional rendering is defined is not tested. So, how do I test the conditional rendering?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create two different test cases passing props to your component. For instance:

```
const yourProps = {
    email: {
      primary: {
         isPending: true // create test cases passing a different value
      },

    },
  }

  const component = mount(<YourComponent {...yourProps} />)
```

Comment: @pranami I am glad it helped you out! Happy coding!

Comment: @pranami by the way, you could also consider adding a snapshot for this test case, example `expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()`

Comment: I have already added a snapshot.Actually the component I am testing has a lot of child components, around 10-15  guess.So 1 doubt that I have which is: for now I have imported all the child components to my test file and trying to call the component inside the shallow/mount to call it, and that way I am seeing that the coverage is getting increased for each file. But I just want to confirm if this is the correct way.Can you please tell  me if I am doing it right?

Comment: Also, I have functions inside my components which are like button clicks that changes the state and opens a dialog box, so how do I test those functions?

Comment: @pranami please create a new question and link it here thanks!

Comment: Please find the link to my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390624/writing-test-cases-using-jest-and-enzyme

Comment: @GibboK How would a snapshot work if it has to match with the other case of the rendering. `expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()` would not match and may have to be updated. If that's the case, how would snapshots be version controlled?

Comment: you need to create the snapshot first time with jest and save it (also on git) and do the comparison next time you test... more info here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing