# Writing test cases using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on writing test cases for a project. I am writing the test for my Container. The container has a function which is as shown below:

```
getContactDetails = (reqObject) => {
    app.outageCenterService.getContact(reqObject).then(
      response => {
        app.logger.getLogger().info('Below is the response...');
        app.logger.getLogger().info(this.state.contactDetails);
        this.setState({contactDetails: response.contactDetails},()=>{});
        if (this.state.contactDetails.isContactPresent) {
          this.setState({ isVisible: true });
        } else {
          this.setState({ isVisible: false });
        }
      },
      reject => {
        app.logger.getLogger().info(reject);
      }
    );
  }
```

While running the test,in the function,the line `app.outageCenterService.getContact(reqObject)` throws an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContact' of undefined`. I understand its because `outageCenterService` is globally defined and jest/enzyme is not able to find it. But I don't know how to solve this issue.

My test looks something like this:

```
  describe('test the OutageAlert Component', () => {
    let outageAlert, errorHandlerFn;
    errorHandlerFn=jest.fn();
    getContactFn=jest.fn();
    outageAlert = shallow(<OutageAlertComponent errorHandler={errorHandlerFn} getContact={getContactFn} />);
  });
```

Can anyone please help me with this on how to write the test case for this scenario?

Comment: is `app` on the global, as `window.app.outageCenterService.getContact`?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider use the globals config

http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#globals-object or create a file and

and create a mock in jest for you global, then you can access it from your test.

Alternatively you could have your container accepting an argument for your contact

`getContactDetails = (reqObject, contact) => { ...}`

so you can pass it in your test and wherever you container is being used.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the code.So, how do I write the test in this case.So, do I have to create a mock function with for `getContactDetails` ? I am sorry I didn't get how to proceed.

Comment: in this case you can use mock with globals-object